# Why the filename header is incomplete if this has space in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, header

I met today an issue, it is strange for me but, maybe, not for experts in C# field.

I have a function called `Download` like this ( a piece of code !)

```
public void Download (string path){
  HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

  try {
           ....//process a 'filePath' variable using the 'path' parameter

               using ( FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream( filePath, FileMode.Open ) ) {
                 ...

                  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName( filePath ) );

                  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Length", fileSize.ToString() );

                  HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite( getContent );
               }
           ...

}
```

If file name mentioned and stored in `path`/`filePath` variable contains space like

`PR SimpleTest.xls`

then the download box contains file name like `PR` with nothing additional.

[image]

If that file name has **NO** space (like `PR_SimpleTest.xls`) then the header comes with `PR_SimpleTest.xls` and I can download as such (appears full filename with his extension).

There are solution(s) to solve issue in case when file name contains space(s) ?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a space and not some other unicode character?

Comment: I'm sure, I made over 50 tests using different file name. I used Google Chrome to view exactly what I sent and what I received in header.

Comment: So you get the same issue with Google Chrome? It's weird because I've just tested it with Google Chrome and it worked fine.

Comment: Not only Chrome ! In all browser. It is because of `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName( filePath ) );` line. If I **remove** space then works very good.

Comment: Since you're using MVC, I believe using `FileResult` would be better way to serve files.

Comment: @SnakeEyes, I've just tested your code under the latest versions of FF, Chrome and IE and it works with the space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A google search for http headers spaces finds this [Knowledge Base article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download) which suggests surrounding the filename with quotes. E.g.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
    "Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName( filePath ) + "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above using:

**Server.UrlEncode(strFileName)**

did not work for me, it resulted in a filename that was:

"My+Long+Filename.txt"

whereas the first solution using **surrounding the filename with quotes** produces:

"My Long Filename. txt"

which is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use Firefox. Look at this link: [Downloading file issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1596070.aspx/1)

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(strFileName))
```

Also look at [ASP.NET MVC Uploading and Downloading Files](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files) and [Writing A Custom File Download Action Result For ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/10/writing-a-custom-file-download-action-result-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx). In MVC you can use special action results.

Comment: Is not about Firefox, is about all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
    "Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=\"" +  filePath + "\"");